# PHP - I want a confirmation popup when someone deletes an article, so it does not instantly delete it

Tags: php

I have an admin panel where you can upload and delete articles from. I want a confirmation to pop up when you select the article you want to delete, to prevent the admin from accidentally deleting the articles.

```
<form action="delete.php" method="get" >
    <select onchange="this.form.submit();" name="article_delete">
        <?php foreach($articles as $article) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $article['article_title']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'm sure there's a ton of stuff out there. I know, I've seen them when I had to Google something like this some time back.

Comment: U need to use ajax for that task

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have, tried multiple stuff to get it working but it either caused the delete to dissapear, didn't stop the instant deletion at all or stopped me from deleting anything.

Comment: Even by posting what you tried and it failed would have shown us an effort. That's what we're here for, to spot errors ;-)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile *"U need to use ajax for that task"* : Not necessarily.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I hear you, but I tried about 10 different things, straight from this website (marked as working answers), and it all didn't work for me. I'll keep it in mind for future posts, though.

Comment: (Aside: we trim out hope-you-can-help, advance thanks and other such material, as they are not considered germane to the post.)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yhea u are correct, but would look much better with

Comment: @YvesLeBorg about the "no attempt" link: Well, in a way yes, but not fully. The OP did state he tried something, it's more of what they didn't post, being what they tried and failed ;-) http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ may have been used/added.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Aye, for sure! :-)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I did, I just removed my efforts and uploaded this. I tried a submit, didn't work. Tried multiple 'if' statements, none did their job. Don't assume I just go out here begging for code, I was in actual need of help. Besides that it's my first post.

Comment: @halfer This is my first post. Just being polite, but I'll take it into account for my further posts on this website, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: No worries @Scott, and welcome. Stack Overflow takes a bit of getting used to! There's plenty of "cultural stuff" over on Meta, [for example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
<select
    onchange="if(confirm('Are you sure?')){this.form.submit();}"
    name="article_delete">
```

It will prompt a alert message.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. Might be some of my PHP interferring with the process.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! I tried a similar if statement, but that didn't do anything for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good anwser by sshopov. But, just to look better, I did it seperately.

```
<select id="x" name="article_delete">

$(document).on('click', '#x', function() {
 if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
   this.form.submit();
 }
});
```